# ORA-00907 error in WHERE DECODE

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having the following query:

```
SELECT TA.* 
FROM TableA TA 
WHERE DECODE(vcConfig, 'Y', TA.ColumnC IS NULL, 1 = 1);
```

Now is `vcConfig` is `Y`.

But my query seems to have a problem with the `IS` from `TA.ColumnC IS NULL`.

The error I am getting is:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: As per my understanding , DECODE is used when you have to get/show the data based on certain values which are expected to be part of result      please go through below documentation for DECODE https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be done like this, you can try this:

```
SELECT TA.*
FROM TableA TA
WHERE (TA.vcConfig = 'Y' AND TA.ColumnC IS NULL)
      OR TA.vcConfig <> 'Y'
```

You can use `decode` to place a value, not a condition.

**EDIT:** Just so you understand the logic, if you wanted it to work with decode you could have done this:

```
SELECT  TA.* 
FROM    TableA TA 
WHERE   DECODE(vcConfig, 'Y', ColumnC  , null ) IS NULL;
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick. Thank you. :-) I was thinking I could do that. But appears not.

Comment: @Tenzin I've updated the answer so you will be able to better understand decode on conditions.

Comment: Thank you, that one is even beter to use I think.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure there would be any difference, more of a convenience thing @Tenzin

Comment: I think the second one is more neat.